# Operators for classes imported from .net dlls

Tags: haxe

I am trying to use Haxe to write scripts for game engines like Unity or Godot.

In both cases I am unable to write a line like

```
Translate(dir * 100.0);
```

where dir is a Vector2 imported from the .net dll of Godot resp. Unity.

The working alternatives I found so far would be

```
Translate(Vector2.op_Multiply(dir, 100.0));
```

which on first sight seems like a bug in the hxcs module, but after some research it seems like a limitation of Haxe's type system.

The other alternative would be to use an abstract type to overload the operator resulting in code like this:

```
Translate(new Vector2WithOps(dir) * 100.0);
```

So my question is: is there a way to get around the explicit cast to the abstract type?

Intuitively it seems like Haxe should be able to apply the operators automatically when importing from C#, and it should be able to infer the type needed for the multiplication and perform the cast to the abstract type implicitly. I understand that there are technical reasons why both is at least difficult, but I am still hoping that there's a way I haven't seen yet.

Comment: Your alternative seems to be the solution to me, and should be more natural if you type `dir` as `Vector2WithOps` instead of `Vector2` from the beginning.

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the @:forward-macro, that's why I hadn't created dir as the abstract type right away, since without that macro I couldn't access the members of the underlying type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So my question is: is there a way to get around the explicit cast to the abstract type?

Yes, abstracts allow defining [implicit casts](https://haxe.org/manual/types-abstract-implicit-casts.html). You can simply add `from Vector2 to Vector2` to the declaration:

```
abstract Vector2WithOps(Vector2) from Vector2 to Vector2 {}
```

That doesn't magically make something like `dir * 100.0` work, however - you still need a way to trigger the cast of `dir` to a `Vector2WithOps`, for instance by assigning it to a variable typed that:

```
var dirWithOps:Vector2WithOps = dir;
```

There's also a special syntax called [type check](https://haxe.org/manual/expression-type-check.html) to trigger the cast:

```
(dir : Vector2WithOps)
```

Ultimately, the most convenient option would be to make sure that you're already working with a `Vector2WithOps` to begin with. That would work as long as you're creating new instances in your own code, but works less well when one is returned from a native API. This reminds me of a Haxe issue that considered allowing operator overloading through [static extensions](https://haxe.org/manual/lf-static-extension.html), which would be quite useful here: [#2803](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/issues/2803)

Comment: I was aware of the implicit casts, but they aren't "implicit enough" for the compiler to infer the type needed for the multiplication operation.
I hadn't created a Vector2WithOps object right away because I wasn't aware of the @:forward macro, so I couldn't access the members of the underlying class.

Comment: Ah, I see. Small but important distinction: `@:forward` is metadata, not a macro. ;)

Comment: You can also overshadow the types loaded by -net-lib with a custom implementation, like it's done in unihx: https://github.com/unihx/unihx/blob/development/src/unityengine/Vector2.hx